# How to transform lowpass fir filter to bandpass fir filter without using a built in function in matlab

Tags: filter-design

The FIR low-pass filter was designed in MATLAB which characteristics are listed below. Coefficient of this filter was written in variable h. Basis on this filter design a band-pass filter with central frequency 1/5(normalized to fs) keeping the same gain and bandwidth. Give the listing in MATLAB(no using buitl-in function) which allow to set down coefficients of designing filter hx.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using Richard Lyons' Understanding DSP? check out section 5.4

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820944/how-to-convert-a-low-pass-filter-to-a-band-pass-filter

Comment: As well as http://www.dspguide.com/ch14/5.htm

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, applying a FIR with impulse response $h_\mathrm{lpf}[n]$ to digital signal is convolution:

$y = x * h_\mathrm{lpf}$, or thanks to the properties of the (discrete) Fourier transform,

$Y = X\cdot H_\mathrm{lpf}$, as convolution becomes multiplication.

Now, making a bandpass out of a low pass can be modeled by shifting the Frequency response $H_\mathrm{lpf}$ in frequency domain. "Shifting" can be represented by a convolution of the low pass filter with a dirac impulse at the desired center frequency:

$H_\mathrm{bpf}= H_\mathrm{lpf} * \delta_{f_\mathrm{center}} $

Again, convolution becomes multiplication when transformed to time domain. The inverse (discrete) Fourier transform of a dirac at ${f_\mathrm{center}}$ is a complex oscillation $e^{2\pi{f_\mathrm{center}}n}$, so this becomes

$y[n] = x * (h_\mathrm{lpf} \cdot e^{2\pi{f_\mathrm{center}}n})$

Comment: would you multiply each coefficient by a discrete value of the sinusoid at the chosen center frequency (i would choose cosine)?


    f = Fs/5;
    for i = 1  : length(h)
            h(i) = h(i) *cos(2*pi*(f/Fs)*i);
    end
    freqz(h,1)

Comment: @AnthonyParks: remember that  $e^{jx} = \cos x + j \sin(x)$, so you'd be convoluting with both; it depends on what you want; I typically mean *complex* (in the sense of "lacking spectral symmetry") band pass filters.

Comment: @AnthonyParks: to be more specific here, $\cos(x) = \frac12 \left(e^{jx}+e^{-jx}\right)$, which means that multiplying with $\cos{(f_\mathrm{center} t)}$ yields to one passband at $-f_\mathrm{center}$ and one at $+f_\mathrm{center}$, whereas the complex sinusoid only produces one passband.